# How can I create a task for two developers to support testing?

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, ms-project-2010

I'm trying to create a timeline for server migration. Typically when it comes to testing our developers spend about 25% of their time supporting the testing. (Running batch processes, answering questions, etc) so I want to have a task for the two developers that run alongside the task for the testing. Each developer should be on the task at 25% and be able to be scheduled for other tasks while the testing is happening.

And I want auto-scheduling because the entire point is to get Project to calculate the schedule for me. Basically things will change based on when we get the servers, so I need to be able to put in the date of each server environment and have Project calculate everything out from there. But devs can be configuring one environment while the prior is being tested while spending a portion of their time supporting the testing.

So for example of what I'd *like* to see:

```
Testing 120h? 7/15-7/30 Kathy
Support 60h?  7/15-7/30 Mike[25%], Tim[25%]
Other   8h?   7/18-7/20 Mike
```

I've tried every combination of Task Type/Effort Driven I can think of but it never quite works. The closest I got was using Fixed Work, which sets the "Support" task to the right dates but the "Other" task ends up being pushed out until after "Support." Also, it has a duration of 120h? making it harder for me to read the hours from for an estimate...

So any idea how I can get it to do what I want?

EDIT: I just found out you can set the amount of "Work" in the Task Details Form (yay for hidden fields!) but it isn't really helping anything.

Comment: 25% of what? Which capacity? Daily, hourly, monthly?